# Apple MacBook pro android studio flutter

Tags: ios, macos, flutter

i needed a MacBook pro to release my flutter app,
I found a used Apple MacBook pro model

```
late 2011, OS v 10.11 Elcaptain
```

With

```
2.5Gh 8gb ram
```

Can i use this macbook to release flutter apps, and open an Apple developer account?
I have no idea about apple store, do they require specific OS version?
Or its gonna be a waste of money and i need newer macbook
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> I needed a MacBook pro to release my flutter app

Fallacy. You don't / didn't need MacBook pro for the task. Be precise, you need Xcode and to run Xcode you need macOS.

> I have no idea about apple store, do they require specific OS version?

Well, why didn't you figure this out for yourself? This is why you are getting downvoted, I see no research effort on your end...

Flutter docs: https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios

Apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/ios/submit/

Here let me point out the important part: **"Starting April 2021, all iOS and iPadOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with Xcode 12 and the iOS 14 SDK."**

And then you do some more research, and you find out what is needed for Xcode 12 to run:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-12-release-notes

**"Xcode 12 requires an Intel-based Mac running macOS Catalina 10.15.4 or later."**

With that sorted you can check if the machine in question is compatible with macOS Catalina: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210222

And now you have all the information that you need to draw a conclusion.

**NOPE**, the oldest you can go is: MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012), MacBook Air (11-inch, Mid 2012), MacBook (Retina, 12-inch, Early 2015), iMac Pro (2017), iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2012), Mac mini (Late 2012), Mac Pro (Late 2013).

PS.

> late 2011... Or its gonna be a waste of money and i need newer macbook Thank you.

Buying a decade old machine is always a waste of money, regardless if it is compatible with the required OS and software... It is severely outdated and most importantly UNRELIABLE at this point.